# cofoundry 0.40 hangfire admin section

Tags: c#, hangfire, cofoundry

I am trying to enable the hangfire dashboard for cofoundry admin
using the `Cofoundry.Plugins.Hangfire.EnableHangfireDashboard` boolean

Program snippet:

```
public class HangfireOvverideSetting : IDependencyRegistration
{
    public void Register(IContainerRegister container)
    {
        var registrationOptions = new HangfireSettings() { Disabled = false, EnableHangfireDashboard = true };
        //  container.Register<IMyService, MyService>(registrationOptions);

        // OR use the static helper

        container.Register<IHangfireServerInitializer>(RegistrationOptions.Override());
    }
}
```

How to go about enabling here?

Answer (score 1):

Once the the *Cofoundry.Plugins.BackgroundTasks.Hangfire* NuGet package is installed, Hangfire will be automatically registered and set up.

The Hangfire dashboard is disabled by default, but to enable it you should only need to update the application setting in your appsettings.json:

```
{
    "Cofoundry:Plugins:Hangfire:EnableHangfireDashboard": true
}
```

It will then be accessible in your admin site at '/admin/hangfire'. There was an error with the setting delimiter in the docs, but that's now been fixed.

You do not have to override the `IHangfireServerInitializer` to enable this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

thats my jspn app  settings   when i tried use the url u said it returned error msg:SqlException: Invalid object name 'HangFire.AggregatedCounter'.
 and i didnt see it create the usual hangfire tables in the db when the app started. i see all teh cofoundry tables but not the hangfire ones.

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",

  "Cofoundry": {
    "Plugins": { "Hangfire": { "EnableHangfireDashboard": true } },
    "Database": {
      "ConnectionString": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=StratusSite;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
    }
  }
}
```